# How to intercepting SMS on Android when the application Samsung ChatON is installed?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, samsung-mobile, intercept

I have a BroadcastReceiver that receives the sms arriving on the phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) and displays a notification containing the information of sms.
It works ok.
When the "Samsung ChatON" application is upgraded to the latest version in google play store my BroadcastReceiver stops working. Sms notifications are not displayed in my application. All sms are intercepted by the application "Samsung ChatOn".
It would be a matter of priority BroadcastReceiver? I already placed high values​​.

Excerpt of BroadcastReceiver of my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<!-- SMS -->
 <receiver 
   android:name=".receiver.ReceiverSms">         
   <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:priority="999">
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue, I'll try and add some more to the scenario though.  (Also on Galaxy S4, btw)  If I have the stock messaging application set as the default SMS application, my application DOES receive the intent.  If I use another application (Hello SMS, for example), I no longer receive the intent.  To further add to the test weirdness, if I use Android 4.4 (cyanogenmod) on the Galaxy S4, this is NOT an issue, and I DO receive the intent, but stock Galaxy S4 (Android 4.3 at the moment) has the issue.  Also, running on a Galaxy Nexus with 4.4 works fine with Hello SMS and my application receives the intent.

Hope this helps anyone else out there, and if you have something to add or potential solutions, please add them.